# SimpleMembershipProvider not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I started a new internet project with VS2012 and am trying to just restructure my project a bit and I can't seem to keep the SimpleMemberhsipProvider working.  Basically, all I've done is move the models objects into a core project along with a couple other items.  I've implemented Ninject and am trying to abstract Entity a bit by using a repository pattern to get my data.  I really don't feel as though I've changed much with the current project, but for some reason when I start the application now I get:

> {"The Role Manager feature has not been enabled."}

The ActionFilter that is supplied by the framework is where the error is thrown when:

> WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

is called.

Here is some of the stacktrace:

> [ProviderException: The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.]
>   System.Web.Security.Roles.EnsureEnabled() +9561885
>   System.Web.Security.Roles.get_Provider() +8
>   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeProviders(DatabaseConnectionInfo
>   connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String
>   userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +104
>   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String
>   connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn,
>   String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +100
>   InoutBoard.Core.Infrastructure.Filters.SimpleMembershipInitializer..ctor()
>   in c:\Users\Kyle\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\InoutBoard\InoutBoard.Core\Infrastructure\Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs:42
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The ASP.NET Simple Membership database
>   could not be initialized. For more information, please see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588]
>   InoutBoard.Core.Infrastructure.Filters.SimpleMembershipInitializer..ctor()
>   in c:\Users\Kyle\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\InoutBoard\InoutBoard.Core\Infrastructure\Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs:46

I'm hosting the code on github at the following link https://github.com/keroger2k/InoutBoard

Comment: take a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Comment: @RickAndMSFT I've read that already.  It was a great post however it didn't seem to answer my question?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**First way**

Check the [sphair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14148462/188268) out (in current thread).

**Second way**

Add following assemblies to the `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="WebMatrix.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add assembly="WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
</system.web>
```

**Update**

The `WebMatrix.WebData` assembly contains a start up method to initialize Membership/Role providers and enable RoleManager (`PreApplicationStartCode.Start`). But ASP.NET couldn't find that to run in your case. By adding these two lines of code, we force ASP.NET to search these assemblies for `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute(s)`.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why this is required?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation, added.

Comment: See also my suggested answer below regarding setting the references to local copy.

Comment: Howcome the default `Internet Application` doesn't have to use this? Where does that code call this?

Comment: Default internet application sets WebMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData references as CopyLocal = True.

Comment: I just want to note that this also solved my problem when trying to implement this in a WCF backend.

Answer (score 10):

In case others are getting this error and the above solution doesn't work, like in my case.  It said invalid child object when I tried to add in the assemblies markup.  I had to specify the roleManager and membership tags  as below.  Once I did that the update-database worked.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" 
             type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same error running at my hosting company (WinHost.com - they are excellent BTW).

My solution was to add to the web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of adding the assemblies to the web.config as Mehdi Golchin suggests, an alternative is to change the assembly references on WebMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData to CopyLocal=True.

Comment: I agree. I found out the same. If I had continued reading the answers it could have saved me some time :)

Comment: I did this on a whim for some other reason (why is this loaded but this isn't? kind of a thing) and was extremely perplexed by it.

Answer (score 0):

add the key to the Web.Config as the page:

http://devbla.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/corrigindo-o-erro-no-aspnet-the-role-manager-feature-has-not-been-enabled/

[]'s