# ASP MVC Authorize Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

When I Use :

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index() {
    ....
    return View();
}
```

OR

```
[Authorize(Users="john")]
public ActionResult Index() {
    ....
    return View();
}
```

My Script Working Well But When I Use :

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult Index() {
    .....
    return View();
}
```

**Error:**

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>    establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>    was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>    SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>    Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>    Specified).

Comment: Is this using AspNet.Indentity?

Comment: Yes  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

Comment: You have a sql server connection problem. not related to `Authorize`.

Comment: Can u show your DbConext and web config?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleMembership, MVC4, AuthorizeAttribute and Roles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342398/simplemembership-mvc4-authorizeattribute-and-roles)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution.  In my *web.config*:

```
1.<modules>
2.<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
3.<remove name="RoleManager" />
4.</modules>
```

---

I added the line 3, and the new *AspNet.Identity* code took over allowing me to use `User.IsInRole(..)`

Comment: It helped me a lot, thanks. Do you know why is this required? I downloaded the sample for Identity from NuGet and there is no such code in Web.config.