# When are the roles initialized in MVC 4? Not after a successful login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roles, simplemembership

Want to set some role based dependencies (Ioc, Ninject). But after a successful login the role of the user is unknown. Where and when to apply the injection? Can I force the initialization of roles? Or do I have to fetch them myself?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            DoRolebasedObjectBinding(model.UserName);   // THIS IS THE WRONG PLACE!
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

The applicatin starts with the HomeContoller (no role set), after the succesful login the appllication is redirected to de HomeController (see standard code above) and now the role is set... 
One trick is to force the roles to be initialized in the HomeController by adding all roles or an addtional "common" role

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Common")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DoRolebasedObjectBinding(User.Identity.Name);
```

But this forces a login an also forces the HomeController as a start point. Hopefully is an "elegant" place to call my DoRolebasedObjectBinding.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "role based model binding", can you be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: Based on the name: WebSecurity.Login, it appears you are doing your own validation and not using membership provider. If this is the case, you will need to take care of loading the roles for the authenticated user on each request. The way you have it now, the DoRolebasedObjectBinding() would set a cookie, which you would then need to read and populate the roles (create Identity and Principal)

Comment: The object injection is based on the role of the logged-in user. The role is set somewhere after the login, but is not yet set at the moment I expected (directly after a succesful login).

Comment: A login just sets a cookie, the roles etcetera are set during the next request (from the now submitted cookie) is this what you ask for?

Comment: The question is: is there a place, a hook where I can do my role-based actions?

Comment: What role-based actions are you referring to? Are you trying to assign a role to a user? You should do that during creation of the user, not login. Where does the method DoRolebasedObjectBinding come from. Please provide the source code for this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Role based authentication in the new MVC 4 Internet template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257232/role-based-authentication-in-the-new-mvc-4-internet-template-using-simplemembers), the answer is rather simple: do it yourself:

```
var roles = Roles.Provider;
string[] rolesArr = roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
```