# simplemembership "remember me" logon fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I'm getting the following exception, intermittently, when accessing an [Authorize]'d action.  It seems to work some of the time, and then fail other times, but its definitely worse when I login and select the "remember me" button.  If I log off, and then immediately log back in, there is no error, so the text below can't be exactly accurate...there's something ELSE going on here, but I'm at a loss to identify it.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
    A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
    establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
    found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name
    is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
    connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - 
    Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Heres the full stack trace

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install)
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureSqlExpressDBFile(String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
   at System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   at Glimpse.Mvc3.Plumbing.GlimpseAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

#### Edit 1

Here's the requested InitializeDatabaseConnection:
`WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("UserDB", "tblPortalUsers", "ID", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);`

#### Edit 2

I just noticed something odd in the middle of that stacktrace:

```
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureSqlExpressDBFile(String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
   at System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role)
```

Why is this code trying to create an MDF File?  My data lives on a SQL server, with a connection string name of UserDB, defined in web.config as:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UserDB" connectionString="data source=NORWAY\DEV;initial catalog=SOMEDB;persist security info=True;user id=MYUSER;password=MYPASS" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DALEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.DAL.csdl|res://*/DAL.DAL.ssdl|res://*/DAL.DAL.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=NORWAY\DEV;initial catalog=SOMEDB;persist security info=True;user id=MYUSER;password=MYPASS;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What would cause it do deviate from the specified DB, and to try and spin up a new MDF to store membership data?  Why does this ONLY happen when a user is using their "remember me" cookie to logback in? (I think so, anyway...haven't been able to prove that yet)

Comment: How your WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(...) method looks like?

Comment: updated with the requested info

Comment: what is your database columns??
Is connection name right in UsersContext??
Do you set correct your Sql Server Protocols??
Which browser do you use for test??
And which pages need login??

Comment: I've tested with FF and IE, so far, but I'll see if I can get it to fail in some others. All pages require login, with a tiny handful of exceptions (login pages, etc). Not sure what your asking in regard to columns and user context. You've picked up that it works just fine, if I don't keep 'remember me" on (though it does seem to happen toward the end of the timeout period), right? It 'mostly' works, but in a few areas, it runs down. I'm thinking that eliminates trivial DB setup questions, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your stack trace, it seems that the `SimpleRoleProvider` hasn't been initialized:

```
at System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
```

Based on [the code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a19eb63170f9#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleRoleProvider.cs), the only way you should get this stack trace is if the `InitializeCalled` property is `false`:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
   if (!InitializeCalled)
   {
       return PreviousProvider.GetRolesForUser(username);
   }
   ...
```

This internal property is set by the `InitializeRoleProvider` method of [the `WebSecurity` class](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a19eb63170f9#src/WebMatrix.WebData/WebSecurity.cs), which is called from the `InitializedDatabaseConnection` method.

Are you absolutely sure that your `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` call is executed every time the application starts?

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but I think so....I have an actionFilterAttribute called `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute`, which is decorating my AccountController class as a whole.  This class is at least partially included in my _Layout for the app header (I've got a current user manager / logout partial view).  Does this attribute need to go on other controllers?  SHould I decorate EVERY controller with it, just in case?

Comment: @reidLinden: It sounds like the problem occurs when your AppPool is recycled. If the user hits a controller other than your `AccountController` for their first request, the simple membership hasn't been initialized. I'd be inclined to add the attribute to every controller which requires authorization, or move the initialization code to `Application_Start`.

Comment: I've put it in `App_Start | FilterConfig.cs ==> filters.Add(new InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute());` .... so far it appears to be working (based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257232/role-based-authentication-in-the-new-mvc-4-internet-template-using-simplemembers)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about InitializeSimpleMembership, because your all pages need login..

Try this

[IsUserInRole Error with SimpleMembership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933327/isuserinrole-error-with-simplemembership/14999288#14999288)

Don't forget to change your settings like this

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("UserDB", "tblPortalUsers", "ID", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Because you change your column name on your database "UserProfile" to "tblPortalUsers"

Comment: no...autoCreateTable is DEFINITELY not what I wish to happen.  But you're generally right about the login bits, see Richard Deeming's comment about appPool recycling above.