# Simpleroleprovider causing remote transaction inside transactionscope

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, transactionscope, simplemembership, distributed-transactions

I am in the process of upgrading asp.net membership to the new simplemembership provider in MVC4.  This is an Azure/Sql Azure app which runs fine on localhost but fails when deployed.  I have code in a transaction as follows:

```
            TransactionOptions toptions = new TransactionOptions();
            toptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable;
            using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, toptions))
            {
                try
                {
                   ... do a bunch of database stuff in a single dbContext ...

                   var roleprov = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
                   string[] roles = roleprov.GetRolesForUser(Username);
                   // above line fails with The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D024)
                 }
             }
```

I am using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257232/role-based-authentication-in-the-new-mvc-4-internet-template-using-simplemembers) to populate the Roles classes.  The stack trace seems to indicate that it is indeed trying to fire off a sub-transaction to complete that call.  The simplemembership tables are in a different db.  How can I retrieve role info from the role provider inside the context of a separate transaction?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `GetRolesForUser` causes a new connection to open to a second database, and that in turn picks up that it is in a `TransactionScope`. In turn this ([MSDN - System.Transactions Integration with SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172070.aspx)) then promotes to the DTC. You could try a few options:

**Get roles before the transaction starts**

You could retrieve `string[] roles` *outside* your `TransactionScope`. Is there a reason you need to get them inside the scope? Given that you say:

> How can I retrieve role info from the role provider inside the context of a separate transaction

it sounds like you could get the role info before the `TransactionScope` and have no problems.

**Turn off transactions on the simple membership connection string**

You can tell a connection string not to take part in transactions by putting "enlist=false" (see [`SqlConnection.ConnectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)) in the connection string, so this might be one option for you if you never need transactions on the database you use for Simple Membership.

**Try opening the Simple Membership connection before the transaction**

<strike>For `SimpleRoleProvider` it creates it's database object, and then opens it the first time it uses it. But, it doesn't close it until ...</strike>. *Scratch that, the connection is opened on each call to `GetRolesForUser` so you are out of luck. I was thinking you could call `GetRolesForUser` once before `TransactionScope` is opened, and then again inside the scope using the already open connection - you can't.*

**Play with the `IObjectContextAdapter`**

*Disclaimer*: I can't promise this will work as I can't test with your setup.

You can play tricks to prevent promotion with two connection strings by opening the non-transaction connection string outside the transaction scope first, and then the transaction shouldn't be promoted. This can also be used if you cause the same connection to `Close` and then `Open` inside the same transaction scope (which would otherwise cause promotion).

You could try this with your context, and see if that stopped the GetRolesForUser promoting the transaction, but I doubt that would work as `GetRolesForUser` causes the connection to open if it isn't already. As I can't test in your scenario, I will include it in case it helps.

```
using (var db = new ExampleContext())
{
    var adapter = db as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter;
    using (var conn = adapter.ObjectContext.Connection)
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            // perform operations
            db.SaveChanges();
            // perform more operations
            db.SaveChanges();
            // perform even more operations
            db.SaveChanges();

            //  If you don't complete, the transaction won't commit and you will lose the changes
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end, I found a way to pull the Roles out of the transactionscope.  It's a little awkward, but it worked.  I found a good article on the issue [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/handling-transactions-in-sql-azure.aspx)

Comment: @AldenG. Yup, so that ("_When you have multiple connections to different databases._) confirms what I said above. In the end did you use `SqlTransaction` instead? I left that option out as I assumed you needed to stick with Roles and DbContext to reduce coupling to the database.

Comment: I played around with SqlTransaction for an hour and couldn't find a way to make it play nicely with entity framework.  Pulling it out of the transactionscope ended up the simplest solution, and with a couple extension methods to access roles, the code ended up clean enough.  Thanks for the help.