# Storing password in session variable secure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am developing an application in ASP MVC 4.0. I have a login page which contains text box for entering user name and password. I used session variables to store user name and password for further authentication process. Is this a secure way? Or is there any other secure method to store passwords for further use untill the user log out ?

Answer (score 1):

Please do not store user credentials in the session state. Once the user is authenticated using the MVC framework the user credentials are not needed until the session expires. If you need to check user privileges use the built in roles.

[Role based authentication in the new MVC 4 Internet template using simplemembership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257232/role-based-authentication-in-the-new-mvc-4-internet-template-using-simplemembers)

http://codeutil.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/forms-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-4/

Why do you need user password after they log in?

Comment: I used password to prevent the user from accessing the Controller Actions using Action Filter.