# How to use SimpleMembership with an existing application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I know many posts deal with this issue but all of them talk about how to set SimpleMembership but not how to call it after. I mean after creating the SimpleMembershipInitializer and plugged it with my database etc, how to force my application to check if the user is authenticated and to oblige him/her to authenticate if he/she is not and then how to configure the authorisations : what pages he/she can see depending on the roles.
Can  somebody explain this part please ?

Comment: If your question is specific to SimpleMembership, I think most of them are answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257232/role-based-authentication-in-the-new-mvc-4-internet-template-using-simplemembers?rq=1.  If you have more general questions about how authentication and roles work in MVC4, you might try searching without the keyword "SimpleMembership".

Comment: OK thanks. But now I can't log in. Every user seems to be never found but if I try to register the same user twice, I get an exception saying "Username alreay in use". So I guess the application can find the users table. And when I register a new user, the password field is always null in my database. Is there something specific to do with the pwd ?