# Role of login user in Index page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to run the following code in Index controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(User!=null)
    {
        if(0==(Roles.GetRolesForUser(username).ToList().Contains("administrator")))
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

I got an exception at `GetRolesForUser` when the Index page loads especially when the `User` is not null (the user is online/logged in)

The exception asks me to call `WebSecurity's InitializeRoles` in _appStart.cshtml file

Comment: Please post the `roleManager` section of your web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

The `Controller.User` property will never be null. When a user is not logged in, `User` will still reference an `IPrincipal` instance. However, `User.Identity.Name` will be equal to an empty string. Also, `User.IsAuthenticated` will equal `false`.

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (User.IsInRole("administrator"))
    {
        // do something
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you have to enable rolemanager in web.config.

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12980969/1502563

Snippet from linked answer below:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" 
         type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Oh and of course - you need to create the role administrator too.

See these links on some ways to do it from scratch:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/09/05/seeding-membership-amp-roles-in-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx

http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/